# CMake run command before add_library

Tags: cmake

I am trying to test some new things in C.

I have a shared library that gets built by Rust. The goal is that I can include the Rust project inside of the C project and have CMake automatically include the project.

So really my goal is to run the `cargo build` command before the `add_library` and before the project links.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# FindWebserver

if(WIN32)
    set(Webserver_LIBRARY libwebserver.dll)
else()
    set(Webserver_LIBRARY libwebserver.so)
endif()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL Debug)
    set(Webserver_LIBRARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/webserver/target/debug)
else()
    set(Webserver_LIBRARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/webserver/target/release)
endif()

set(Webserver_LIBRARY_PATH ${Webserver_LIBRARY_DIR}/${Webserver_LIBRARY})

if(EXISTS ${Webserver_LIBRARY_PATH})
    set(Webserver_FOUND ON)
else()
    set(Webserver_FOUND OFF)
endif()

# Build webserver

if(NOT Webserver_FOUND)

    add_custom_target(
            TARGET Webserver ALL
            COMMAND cargo build webserver --package webserver --lib <IF:<CONFIG:Debug>?,,--release>
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/webserver
            BYPRODUCTS ${Webserver_LIBRARY_PATH}
            USES_TERMINAL
    )

    set_target_properties(Webserver PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
    add_dependencies(BasicWebServer Webserver)

endif()
```

**Edit:** As requested, I have uploaded the full [CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/uaSnEfUn) file.

`BasicWebServer` is the project name. Unfortunately I get errors such as:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (add_dependencies):
  Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target
  "BasicWebServer".
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a complete CMakeLists.txt you are using?

Comment: @gordan.sikic sorry for late reply i was gone past couple days. no that is not the complete cmake file. i didn't copy in the `project(...)` and `add_executable(...)` because it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Do you want to make `cargo build` part of the configuration phase, or the part of the build phase?

Comment: BTW, the error you are stating is **NOT** connected to the `cargo build` but to the missing target `BasicWebServer` that is not mentioned in the part of CMakeLists.txt you presented. Make a minimal, but complete example that shows the problem, and someone (or even myself) will be able to help you.

Comment: @gordan.sikic Build phase. Also updated to include the full CMakeLists.txt file. For more context, it's a CLion project with a RustRover (shared lib) project in a subdirectory "webserver" as reflected in the cmakelist.